# Is there a way to configure JUnit 5 thread count using a command line argument?

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5, spring-test

Currently, to set the thread count, I have to update the following property inside **junit-platform.properties** file:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=5
```

Is there a way to configure the thread count using a command line argument?

Comment: Something here may help: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-config-params

Comment: Why not let JUnit handling that? You have configured with fixed ... but you could use to configer the number of CPU's based?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Slaw.
The following command works like a charm:

```
mvn clean -Djunit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism='10' test
```